# CakePHP 4.x shows unwanted character preceding Flash message success

Tags: html, css, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

When using edit Article page through the ArticlesController to edit an article, the page redirects from the edit page to the Articles index.php page and the success message appears. However, the message.success div is showing a V character preceding the success message "Your article has been updated."

See image:

[Flash message.success "Your article has been updated."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl9st.jpg)

Partial ArticlesController class:

```
class ArticlesController
{

 public function edit($slug)
 {

  if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
     $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));
     return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
 }
```

All that's required to display it on the templates/Articles/index.php page is:

```
 <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
```

Resulting html added to index.php in templates/Articles/index.php

```
<div class="message success"    onclick="this.classList.add('hidden')"> event
 ::before
Your article has been updated.
</div>
```

See image:

[Flash message.success "Your article has been updated."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl9st.jpg)

Looks like ::before is causing the "V" character to appear with the message box, then the message "Your article has been updated." is added and without a space between the "V".

I have checked the element directory, but can't find a connection.

Does anyone know how I can remove this "V"?

Answer (score 0):

Check your templates, specifically your layout template (likely **[`templates/layout/default.php`](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.4.1/templates/layout/default.php)**). Sounds like you possibly included `webroot/css/home.css` (which has a [**`.success:before` rule**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.4.1/webroot/css/home.css#L61-L64) that relies on the CakePHP Dingbats font to be used) on a page that is not the home page ([**`templates/Pages/home.php`**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.4.1/templates/Pages/home.php)).

Comment: Well, it is in the success::before rule under content: \0056, generated content. Must be for more customizing effects. Thanx for the response.

Comment: Germany huh, ya ya goodensite!

Comment: Since your dingbats comment, CakePHP 4.x was hacked and CakePHP 4.x homepage characters were changed to wingdings. Any brainwashing technology as well?

Comment: @CaliforniaKidd I have no idea what you're talking about. The fix for the problem is to not include `home.css` on pages that aren't actually the home page. That CSS file should only be included in the `templates/Pages/home.ctp` template, and nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect in browser and check css and destination of css.

Sample ::
[image]

Comment: Ah ha RiTeSh, awesome, the V is an ascii representation. I didn't know where to find it. Apparently, it is in the home css file under success::before under the content rule, content: \0056; I wonder what is the reasoning behind that. I havn't fixed it yet, just wanted to thank you for the quick response. In the meantime, I started working on Drupal, might need your help in the future, thanx again.